# MMAP buffer kernel writes are not seen by user space

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

i have a kernel driver which shares a buffer with the user space layer.
Everything seemed to work fine in my VM prototype (Ubuntu, Kernel 5.4) but when i moved my code to the target (same kernel but this is an embedded distro) I can clearly see that  Kernel writes to the buffer (using memcpy, or memset) are not reflected in the User space side of the buffer.

Note that, i use direct buffer accesses on both sides. There is no concurrency issue, as the Kernel writes to, then the user space reads from.
I ended up believing this is a cache issue ... as the same code works perfectly in my VM.

The buffer size is 4 * PAGE_SIZE.
It is allocated as follows:

```
    int _size = (SFP_BUFFER_SIZE + (PAGE_SIZE-1)) & ~(PAGE_SIZE-1);
    input_buffer = (char*) kzalloc (_size, GFP_KERNEL); // aligned on page boundary
    if (!input_buffer) {
        dev_dbg(&dev, "open/ENOMEM (input_buffer)\n");
        status = -ENOMEM;
        goto err_all
```

When mmap'ing, i used the following code pattern:

```
vma->vm_ops = &fpgadrv_vm_ops;
vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
pfn = virt_to_phys((void*)(input_buffer)) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
if (remap_pfn_range (vma, vma->vm_start, pfn, size, vma->vm_page_prot))
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "remap page range failed\n");
    return -EAGAIN;
}
```

User space code, and kernel code user memcpy to update the buffer. Note also that I cannot use write/read entry points, as they are already used for very specific operations.
The user code is calling mmap as follows:

---

```
buf = mmap(NULL, BUF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, device_fd, 0);
if (buf == MAP_FAILED)
{
    perror("USERDRV:cannot mmap");
    return -1; // for testing, ignore the return code and continue
}
```

and upon IOCTL call, the kernel would fill up the mmap buffer as follows:

```
case IOCTL_RESET:
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "FPGADRV: IOCTL RESET");
    // reset the buffer (zero + put back the signature)
    memset(input_buffer, 0xA5, SFP_BUFFER_SIZE);
    memcpy((void*)(input_buffer), (void*)signature, 10);

    break;
```

Is there something more i should do to make sure the pages are not cached (assuming this is the cause of my pb) ?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the advice. I tried but it didn't help :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `pgprot_noncached` or do any cache flushing if the buffer is allocated from main memory and is only accessed by the CPU.

Comment: As an experiment, what happens if you use `volatile` qualified access to the buffer on the user side?

Comment: @IanAbbott i tried (and even wrote a volatile compatible version of memcpy and memset, but it didn't help !

Comment: What CPU are you using?

Comment: That's a Cortex A7 (stm32mp151 soc)

Comment: here is the way it is allocated --- I put it in the initial question for better formatting

Comment: @stackinside Thanks. There is no special logic between IOCTL and the read, that's true. Not too sure how to do that, though, but probably on a signal basis  ....

Comment: I will have look at what you suggested

Comment: I added some sleeps as suggested, and it definitely improved the reading. now i can see the kernel writes. There are still some issues to solve, as not the entirety of the kernel writes can be seen. For example, on IOCTL, kernel is painting the the first 512 bytes of the buffer but and the user space sees only a part of them, with some holes. Heading to packet_mmap to get new ideas .... Also, i think i have seen a post about these holes sometimes ago

Comment: nope, O_NONBLOCK was not set. But I  just noticed that by adding MAP_LOCKED to MAP_SHARED flags did improved the behavior, except that still the kernel writes are only seen upto the 128th byte ..... it is worth noting that my target device has no disk, only nand flash, Maybe this is causing big inefficiencies in VM operations ?

Comment: Great ! this was the killer flag, it now works perfectly. I was struggling a bit with the packet_mmap way (segfaults) but this flag just solved my issue i believe. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, yes, feel free to post as a suggestion.

Comment: Seems parts of this discussion has been removed. I'm looking into similar issues as described here. Can you conclude what was the 'killer flag' that solved this for you?

Comment: Hi, actually adding MAP_LOCKED to MAP_SHARED was the killer. I tried to upvote, but it seems mu reputation is not suficient yet, sorry